# \color{} inserts blank line after environment!

Tags: color, environments, empty-line

I use `\begin{@empty}\color{red} . . . \end{@empty}` to delimit colored text. But it inserts an extra blank line after `\end{@empty}` in the following situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{@empty}\color{red}%
Paragraph starts abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
\[
  a = 1
\]%
\end{@empty}%

New paragraph ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl
\end{document}
```

**If you comment out `\color{red}`, this blank line is gone!** I wonder how to prevent this blank line while using `\color{red}`.

By the way, it's a bit annoying that you need `%` like `\end{@empty}%` to prevent the empty line even without `\color{red}`.

Ultimately I'd like an environment which has *absolutely no impacts* except for limiting the range of `\color{red}`.

I use lualatex and pdflatex from the latest texlive distribution.

**Edit:** I failed to make it clear that my goal is to define an environment that colors the enclosed text and has not other impacts. In the process of trying to write such an environment, I encountered the above problem.  My ultimate goal is to switch between colored and uncolored text quickly and systematically with a minimal markup. The `monochrome` option David mentions below would work except I still don't know how to avoid the extra blank line. (Except I could remove the empty line after the math and use `\hspace*{\parindent}` to indicate the beginning of the paragraph.) The `luacolor` solutions is ideal except I don't know how to make sure my publisher uses luatex. . . .  (I mentioned pdflatex and lualatex only to imply the problem occurs on both compilers.)

Answer (score 8):

Groups in TeX are not no-op they have effects, so if you want to have no observable effect on spacing (which is actually surprisingly hard) you need to compensate for the group, not just do nothing.

You can see a similar effect even with a simple `{}` group.

```
a b
```

and

```
a  b
```

produce the same output as the multiple spaces are combined, however

```
a {} b
```

makes a double space, you need

```
a {}b
```

or (closer to the form you used)

```
a {}%
b
```

or (closer to the form I suggest below)

```
a {\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
b
```

to get a single space between a and b.

LaTeX has a standard command to use `\ignorespaces` after the group made by an environment, `\ignorespacesafterend` so this produces the correct spacing without needing `%`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{zz}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\begin{zz}%\color{red}%
Paragraph starts abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
\[
  a = 1
\]
\end{zz}

New paragraph ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl
\end{document}
```

[image]

However if you add the colour

[image]

Note the extra line, really is an extra (white) line of the first paragraph, it is not vertical space, and would not be dropped at a page break.

The fact that it is hard to avoid colour commands affecting spacing is why the `color` package has the `monochrome` option that allows you to disable all colour commands rather than comment them out, this at least makes the spacing consistent between colour and black versions of the document.

The problem is that the `\color` command inserts (again via `\aftergroup`) a colour special to restore the colour, but the presence of this special (or pdf literal primitive) interferes with the end-of-display-math logic for deciding if there is a continuation of the paragraph after the display.

You could (here at least) disable the automatic colour restore and add it by hand in a safer place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{zz}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatletter
\def\restorecolor{\reset@color}
\def\norestorecolor\reset@color{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{zz}\aftergroup\norestorecolor\color{red}%
Paragraph starts abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
\[
  a = 1
\restorecolor
\]
\end{zz}

New paragraph ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a tex-core's problem no?

Comment: @touhami  tex was not designed with colour in mind, that is certainly true `texdoc grfguide` footnote page 6 (been my standard answer to all color issues for last 25 years:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you for the comprehensive answer! So, it seems to me that it's *impossible* (unless you use `luacolor`) to define an environment that colors the text and avoids the extra blank line?  I've tried to encapsulate your commands as `\newenvironment{Colortext}{\aftergroup\norestorecolor\color{red}}{\restorecolor\ignorespacesafterend}`.  But this environment still resulted in the extra line. Perhaps that's why you put your `\restorecolor` in the math, not after it.

Comment: The whole point is to put the restore inside the equation. It is similar to a `proof` environment that automatically adds a QED symbol, but sometimes you need to take manual control with \qedhere to place the marker and stop the automatic one.@Ryo

Comment: What is surprising is that it continues to happen each time there is a dispaly math at end of group.

Comment: @touhami why is that surprising?  If there is a display math at the end, suppress the automatic colour restore and manually add the colour restore inside the display

Comment: suppose that the   group  with color dont end with display math or not followed with blanck line so no problem noticed but if we have later a group (with no color) but end with display math and followed with blanck line the problem appears.

Comment: @touhami I don't understand the comment: a non-coloured group that ends with display math should not be an issue (as long as you ignore spaces)

Comment: should i asq a new question? let's my try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111788/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-touhami).

Answer (score 7):

David has explained what happened. But as you mention lualatex: There you could avoid the problem by using `luacolor`, which uses attributes instead of specials and so doesn't disturb the math spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{@empty}\color{red}%
Paragraph starts abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
\[
  a = 1
\]%
\end{@empty}%

New paragraph ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about downvoting for lack of zz but decided to upvote anyway

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you could edit the environment, it is much easier for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{Color}[1][red]{\color{#1}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\begin{Color}
Paragraph starts: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd
\[
  a = 1
\]
\end{Color} 
New line---not new paragraph---starts: ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl

\begin{Color}[blue]
Paragraph starts: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd ab
\end{Color} 
New line---not new paragraph---starts: ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl ijkl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the op wanted the paragraph to start after the equation

Comment: you have also re-introduced the spurious space before `New`  note it is not indented like the first Paragraph nor flush left like the `paragraph` on the last line.

Comment: I cannot see it :-) ...  thanks

Comment: You fixed the space (as in my answer) but have still not addressed the actual question asked, which is why you get a spurious blank line at the end of the paragraph, simply changing the document text not to have a new paragraph is changing the example not to include the issue, not solving the issue.